# I want to transform the first Jsonfile into the second Jsonfile with javascript:

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, forms, transformation

So How to split values of a Json object like this:
{"key":["value 1","value 2","value 3"]}
into this:
{"zz0": "value 1","zz1": "value 2","zz2": "value 3"}
In my javascript form this is the first Json file:

```
    [
      {
        "fotos": [
          {
            "foto": [ "foto 1" ],
            "tekst": [ "first line.", "second line.", "third line." ]
          },
          {
            "foto": [ "foto 2" ],
            "tekst": [ "first line." ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And this is the second Json File:

```
    [
      {
        "fotos": [
          {
            "foto": "foto 1",
            "zz0": "first line.",
            "zz1": "second line.",
            "zz2": "third line."
          },
          {
            "foto": "foto 2",
            "zz0": "first line."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I am doing the transformation somehow like this:

```
            onSubmit: function (errors, values) {
                if (errors) {
                    $('#res').html('<p>Is er iets fout gegaan?</p>');
                } else {
                    const JSONbasis = values.fotos;
                    lengte = JSONbasis.length;
                    for (let i = 0; i < lengte; i++) {
                        const pValues = Object.values(values.fotos[i]);//values
                        const jsStrVal1 = ('{"foto":' +JSON.stringify(pValues[0]));
                        const jsStrVal2 = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, pValues[1]));
                        const result = jsStrVal1.concat(jsStrVal2);
                        const resultB = result.replace('"{"', '","');
                        const resultC = resultB.replaceAll('","', '","zz');
                        resultArray.push([resultC]);
                    }
                    console.log("resultArray= " + resultArray);
                }
            }
```

But I am sure there is a better way.
Any idea?

Comment: what, if you have more than one element in `foto`?

Comment: In my form there is always only one photo with corresponding lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a new object while iterating the data.

```js
const
    convert = ({ foto: [foto], tekst }) => ({
        foto,
        ...Object.fromEntries(tekst.map((value, index) => [`zz${index}`, value]))
    }),
    data = [{ fotos: [{ foto: ["foto 1"], tekst: ["first line.", "second line.", "third line."] }, { foto: ["foto 2"], tekst: ["first line."] }] }],
    result = data.map(({ fotos }) => ({ fotos: fotos.map(convert) }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was experimenting with the spread (...) syntax. I thought this should be the way to work this out.
So when I transform this object:
const object = {"foto":"fa","tekst":["t1","t2","t3"]};
const newObject = {...object, tekst: { ...object.tekst}};
Result: newObject = {"foto":"fa","tekst":{"0":"t1","1":"t2","2":"t3"}}
A little step in the solution...
But how to transform a more nested object like this one?:
const big_object = {"fotos":[{"foto":"fa","tekst":["t1","t2","t3"]},{"foto":"fb","tekst":["t1"]},{"foto":"c","tekst":["t1"]}]}
But your solution is perfect. Thanx a lot. I love it.

Comment: @backnext, you could map the nested parts.

Comment: map and spread are a bit new to me. I think I will continue with your answer ;-)

Comment: Still a small question: The way in which the 'const declaration' has been used here is unknown to me. Does this only apply to 'convert' or also to 'data' and 'result'? Or should it be 'const convert...'?

Comment: it works like any other declaration types, for example `var` which declares all between keyword and semicolon, separated by comma. additional for `const` it needs values as well.

Comment: I know 'const' is used like var and let... But the way 'const' is used here it seems like this  applies to 'convert, data and result' all together.

Comment: In Chrome Devtools typeof(data) shows 'undefined'. 
When I compose data ending with JSON.stringify(data), this gives an error. And Devtools typeof(data) shows a string.
What's the problem?

Comment: you could use `'use strict';` to prevent using undefined variables. what result do you get for `console.log(data)`? btw, `typeof` is an unary operator which works without braces.

Comment: 'use strict'; in the script makes no difference.
This is showing console.log(data):
{fotos: Array(3)}
fotos: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249743/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-backnext).